# Modifying whitespace before and after list separately using enumitem package

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

I use the [enumitem package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to modify the amount of space related to lists.  One of the options this package can easily modify is `topsep`.  However, this variable controls the vertical space both before and after a list.  I can manually add back some space after the list, but this is just a hack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\begin{document}
I like the lack of vertical space between the end of this paragraph and the beginning of the following list.

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
 \item Item 1
     \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}

I don't like the lack of vertical space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph.

I don't like the lack of vertical space between the end of this paragraph and the beginning of the following list.

\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}

I like the vertical space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph.

To get the best of both worlds,
I use a baseline skip after the list.

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

Now there is a good amount of space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph,
but a bit too much and achieved via a ``hack''.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Question

How can I use this package to modify the amount of space before and after separately?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `before=<code>` and / or `after=<code>` to put the space/some latex code.  If you use

```
\setlist{nosep,after=\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

we get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,after=\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
I like the lack of vertical space between the end of this paragraph and the beginning of the following list.

\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}

I don't like the lack of vertical space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph.

I don't like the lack of vertical space between the end of this paragraph and the beginning of the following list.

\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}

I like the vertical space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph.

To get the best of both worlds,
I use a baseline skip after the list.

\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
%\vspace*{\baselineskip}

Now there is a good amount of space between the end of the previous list and the beginning of this paragraph,
but a bit too much and achieved via a ``hack''.
\end{document}
```

If you want to override this for one `itemize` environment, use

```
\begin{itemize}[after=]
```

Comment: Maybe `\medskipamount` or something like that would look better?

Comment: @Bernard True, but that is up to OP to choose.

Comment: @Bernard I looked [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) for some standard/default amount of vertical space to add and `\baselineskip` seemed to work the best.  Your `\midskipamount` seems to add less than the default amount of space.  Do you have other suggestions?  Preferably I would use the same commands that would have normally been used had `nosep` not been used.

Comment: @Tyson Williams: actually I was unsure whether to propose `\medskipamount` or `bigskipamount`. But maybe it's connected to French typographical tradition, which is rather restrained as to vertical spacings, as you may know.